# I need to make report from one table having two dates column

Tags: mysql

i have two credit bureau we are using 1 for applicant and another for co-applicant , we are giving different customer ID to each, each record captured there own date so i want to display customer ID and date from both bureau which are available in one table column1 and column2  i want to show both details like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdfru.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APpaQ.png)

Comment: unpivot using union..but how do you know customer2 and customer 1 are co-applicants?

Comment: it is just example of customer ID , need date based on ID  union select  customer_ID,  (CRIF_DATE, cibil_date) as 'date'   from gcd_customer_m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.cid,t.col1 from t where col1 is not null
union all
select t.cid,t.col2 from t where col2 is not null;
```

Comment: can we use this join

Comment: Yes either as a sub query or part of a CTE

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
case when col1 is not null then col1 else col2 end,
col1 is not null as 'just_check' 
from t
```